# Output object of two json files with two filters using jq

Tags: json, jq

I have these two json files :

File 0.json

```
{
  "Feline": [
    {
      "Name": "Leo",
      "Race": "Bengal",
      "Weight": "12"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Diego",
      "Race": "Toyger",
      "Weight": "24"
    }
  ]
}
```

File 1.json

```
{
  "Feline": [
    {
      "Name": "Lynx",
      "Race": "Bengal",
      "Weight": "15"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Simba",
      "Race": "Ussuri",
      "Weight": "14"
    }
  ]
}
```

With jq I would like the heaviest Feline whose race is Bengal of these two json file.

So the output will be

```
{
  "Feline": [
    {
      "Name": "Lynx",
      "Race": "Bengal",
      "Weight": "15"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried to combine --slurp and --arg and pipe in max without concrete result.
If someone know how to do this I'll apreciate the help.

Comment: What if there is no single heaviest such feline?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ jq -n '{Feline: [
  [inputs.Feline[] | select(.Race=="Bengal")] | max_by(.Weight)
]}' file1 file2
{
  "Feline": [
    {
      "Name": "Lynx",
      "Race": "Bengal",
      "Weight": "15"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following pipeline:

```
$ jq -s '[.[] | .Feline[] | select(.Race == "Bengal")] | max_by(.Weight) | {"Feline": [.]}' f1 f2
{
  "Feline": [
    {
      "Name": "Lynx",
      "Race": "Bengal",
      "Weight": "15"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: A slight improvement use `map` instead of the `[.[] | ...]`: `'map(.Feline[]|select(.Race=="Bengal"))|max_by(.Weight)|{"Feline":[.]}'`